# How to print to HTML using python as server side script?

Tags: python, html

I have the following html button

```
<td><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" onclick="../cgi-bin/py/GuestBookEntry.py">
<input type="submit" name="gBookSrib" id="gBookSrib" value="Sribble" />
</form></td>
```

My python script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

When i click the button i want my serverside script to execute and create a html page. How do i do that?

My webhost service provider is fatcow. I think he runs apache, is there a way to check it though? Yes he supports python cgi script. He mentioned that if i place my 'py' files inside the cgi-bin, it should work, even without the 'she'bang.

Fatcow does not allow custom modules. Only standard python modules. They had not allowed access to my cgi-bin folder by default, so had to call them, and then the below stuff just worked.

Comment: `sys.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")` to fit the spec. Are you familiar with Apache?

Comment: @khachik - no am new to apache, my webhoster is fatcow.com, but i think he runs it on apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which web server are you using?
For apache2 there is very tidy module called apache2-modpython, that takes care of executing server-side python scripts and returning the result to the client.

Using this module your python would look like:

```
def index (req): return "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>"
```

Let's say this script is called test.py and has the URI http://yourserver.tld/test.py, then your form would look like:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="test.py">
```

Inside the  entry of your site definition add the following lines

```
    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
    PythonDebug On
```

Comment: where do i add the site definition? .htaccess? i have to see how fatcow (my web host service provider) gives access to htaccess files.

Comment: not in htaccess, but in your site definition. By default located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You need a webserver that serves Python code.

There are several different possibilities out there.

- [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/WebDevelopmentWithTwisted) is a webserver written in Python, allowing you to serve content from python with minimal overhead.
- Apache / ngnix + [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) offers a more complete stack to develop a full web application

Comment: Thanks, but how do i install custom modules. My host provider is someoneelse (fatcow.com) he provides support for python cgi, but how do i print to webpage to see output of my python function on button click

Comment: do you have ssh access to your account?

Comment: nope i spoke with the customer care, they support only standard Python 2.5 modules. Nothing more. But i got it to work. Thanks